# Given the file name, how to get it from a directory in shell

Tags: linux, file, shell, find

I want to compare 2 files with the same name in different directories.
$1 and $2 are  2 directories. I can check if there are same name files, but then i don't know how to get the 2nd file..

```
cd $1
    for i in `ls`
do
if [ -f $2/$i ]
then
    echo "find it in another directory"

    GET THE OTHER FILE IN $2, THEN COMPARE THEM

    cmp -s $i THE OTHER FILE
    if [ $? = 0 ]
        echo "they are same"
    else
        echo "they are different"
    fi
fi
done
```

Comment: You can use `comm -12 <(ls "$1") <(ls "$2")` to get comm names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest problem would be spaces in the args - easy to fix, just quote $1 and $2

```
if [ -f "$2/$i" ]
```

But I suspect the problem is that you are CDing into $1, which means $2 is invalid (if it is a relative path)

Solution1) Use absolute paths (e.g. /staff/bathpp/stuff/dir2)

Solution2) If you are expecting relative paths, then grab the current dir before jumping.

```
origDir=`pwd`
...
path2="$origDir/$path2"
```

Personally I'd to some checks so it worked for both.

Comment: Ya, thanks. Another thing is I still don't know how to get the 2nd file, i'm new to shell, i tried find, grep, both not work. Don't know how to get that file so that i can compare.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "get" - if $2 is an absolute path "$2/$i" will 'get' it. If $2 is a relative path then "$origDir/$2/$i"

Answer (score 0):

```sh
for FIRST in $1/*
do
    SECOND=$2/$(basename "$FIRST")
    if [ -f "$SECOND" ]; then
        diff --brief "$FIRST" "$SECOND"
    fi
done
```

N.B. `diff --brief` only outputs when they are different. If you want to see the actual difference, remove the `--brief`.